# Prevent Core Data from creating null objects

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, ios6, nsmanagedobjectcontext

This is the code I use to create a new object. The thing is, if I choose not to save the new object, it creates an empty tableview cell. How can I prevent that from happening?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Add"]) {
        NSLog(@"Setting PersonsTVC as a delegate of PersonDetailTVC");
        StepDetailView *personDetailTVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        personDetailTVC.delegate = self;
        personDetailTVC.title = @"Add New Step";
        NSLog(@"Creating a new person and passing it to PersonDetailTVC");
        Step *newPerson = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Step"
                                                        inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        personDetailTVC.person = newPerson;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Unidentified Segue Attempted!");
    }
}
```

What I've tried so far is inserting the code below after  `personDetailTVC.person = newPerson;`

```
if (newPerson.name == nil) {
    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:newPerson];
    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

    [self performFetch];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

But it isn't a good solution, as it crashes the app because the tableview cell doesn't get deleted, only the object does. 
What I thought that I could do, is automatically delete the first tableview cell if the object is null, but I haven't found a way to do so.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, could you explain better your goal? I cannot understand what you're asking here..thanks

Comment: You should save it. You can delete it later, if it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a guess at what I think is going on here. Please correct any of my assumptions if they are wrong.

- You got a UITableView
- The cells are populated with data from CoreData.
- And you're populating it through NSFetchedResultsController
- The segue is to a PersonDetailVC, which allows the user to enter data for a new managedobject?

What's happening is when you 'insertNewObjectForEntity:' a new blank managedObject is created and inserted into Core Data. NSFetchedResultsController gets notified of the change and new cell gets inserted UITableView. NSFetchedResultsController picks up on the changes, and add a blank cell.

Regardless whether you save the context or not, it's already in your core data store. "Save" is just making sure the changes are reflected in core data's persistent store (sqlite or plist). Core Data exist in memory, the sqlite persistent store is just for persistence only.

The solution is don't insert into core data until the user has entered the data. You shouldn't be doing a core data insert inside a segue.

Solution:
- Segue to PersonDetailVC with no new object created.
- After user finish entering data, user press "save" or "done"
- when pop back from the PersonDetailVC, insert new managedObject into Core Data using the populated fields.
- NSFetchedResultsController will pick up on the changes and modify the UITableView appropriately.

Note: If you're using NSFetchedResultsController, you don't need to [self.tableview reloadData]. The fetchedresultscontroller call it for you after coalescing all the changes.